# Recaptcha: could not open socket

Tags: php, sockets

I don't understand why I'm seeing "could not open socket" right after I click the send button on my form on localhost.

I'm using Wamp and "allow url fopen" and "php_sockets" are checked.

Also I saw that some people solved the problem by changing line 40 in "recaptchalib.php" for:

```
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "www.google.com");
```

to:

```
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", gethostbyname("www.google.com"));
```

or:

```
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "74.125.227.48");
```

Does anyone have an idea where this is coming from?
Thank you in advance.

[EDIT]
I just uploaded the whole thing online on my server instead of localhost and it's working. But still, I'm curious to know why it works online and not on localhost...

Comment: Please show us the code that you're seeing this error on.

Comment: I'm using CakePHP so it's going to be complicated to give a piece of code as it's fractionated in many pieces throughout the framework files. But I just downloaded a customized public and secret key from Google and I downloaded the recaptcha package.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232639/could-not-open-socket